# What is the difference between the equation for linear elasticity and the acoustic wave equation?

Tags: waves, acoustics, elasticity

What is the difference between the equation for linear elasticity and the acoustic wave equation? They both seem to model vibrations propagating through a medium so I'm not sure why we have two different equations for the same phenomenon?

Comment: Without more detail, my off-hand answer from experience is that the linear elasticity equations relate stress to strain through the elastic tensor. This is often used for analysis of static or slowly changing problems. The acoustic equations, while based on linear elasticity, are explicitly set up to result in (propagating) wave solutions assuming small stresses and strains.